# JavaScript/DOM: Can't change any element attributes other than id

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to use JavaScript to modify an existing webpage. I am running my code in Chrome's snippets page after the webpage is loaded. My goal is to overwrite some of the existing attributes of some of the elements on the page.

When I run this code:

```
document.getElementById('foo').readOnly = false;
document.getElementById('foo').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('foo').aaa = '123';
document.getElementById('foo').onClick = '123';
document.getElementById('foo').id = '123';
```

Only the id is changed. The other attributes are untouched. I am checking to see if things have changed by using the html inspector in chrome. 
Is there something that I am missing? I've tried looking for a solution for this problem but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: How are you checking if attributes got set/changes?

Comment: What kind of tag is having id foo?

Comment: Which element are you trying on? `readOnly`, `disabled` and `id` should all work on an HTMLInputElement. `onClick` and `aaa` doesn't exist (they're not IDL attributes). And even if you corrected to `onclick`, onevent properties do not update the corresponding attribute. https://jsfiddle.net/puggjtuj/

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to do it, you're actually just setting properties on a JavaScript object. That's not the same as setting the properties on the HTML element that the object represents.

To do what you're trying to do, you need to use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Comment: That's not true for most IDL attributes. When you set these, they will update the corresponding attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to this:
[Changing HTML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp), 
that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use removeAttribute("readonly") and setAttribute("aaa","123"). After you use the document object to get the id.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. The Element.Attribute technique that I was using was the issue!

Comment: No problem at all